# Oracle 10g OS Authentication fails in SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have set up an externally identified user for our Oracle 10g (10.2.0.3) database like this:

```
CREATE USER "OPS$DOMAIN\USER" IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;
```

Now I am trying to connect from a 10.2.0.1 sqlplus client using

```
connect /@TNS_NAME;
```

however I get

```
Invalid username/password.
```

[Edited]
Here is all the information I can currently give on this issue:

- There are two virtualized Windows 2003 Servers, each running their own Oracle 10.2.0.3 database
- There are two virtualized Windows XP Clients with the Oracle Client 10.2.0.1
- All four machines are on the same virtual host and within the same domain
- The same user is used to log in on both clients
- Client 1 can use OS authentication to connect to Server 1
- Client 1 cannot connect to Server 2 with OS authentication
- Client 2 cannot connect to either database server with OS authentication
- Both Clients can connect to either database server with schema owner/password
- Four months ago, Client 2 could connect to Client 2 with OS authentication. I cannot tell if Client1->Server2 and Client2->Server1 worked, but I am almost certain it did.

Things I have considered:

1. I double checked the os_authent_prefix, which is "OPS$"
2. I tried recreating the user, and made sure everything was written in caps (we had problems in the past when we didn't have all caps)
3. I tried granting the create session privilege (someone suggested that somewhere; didn't help)

What could I be missing / What else could I try?

PS: Database security is not a concern here; I know OS Authentication is [kind of insecure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299/why-is-os-authentication-considered-poor-security-for-oracle-databases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is happening at the client can you please check the below parameter in sqlnet.ora file in the client machine

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

Even after that it does not work you can refer this [article on os-authentication](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/os-authentication.php) to check if any step is missing

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that this afternoon

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. Additionally, I realized my Client 1 cannot connect to Server 2 using OS authentication, looks like I incidentally connected to the wrong server last time. See my updated question

Comment: Can you check the parameter SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)in database Server2.Since this parameter is required in sqlnet.ora in both client and server as per oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/authen.htm

Comment: it's set on all machines

Comment: Can you switch on client and server trace to debug the problem http://www.oracledebugging.com/2011/09/oracle-database-10g-debugging_16.html?m=1

Comment: Finally fixed it. The problem was that the clients were referencing another server for the TNS Names through the `TNSADMIN` registry key. I didn't know that this also makes them search the sqlnet.ora file there. Someone or something placed an empty sqlnet.ora file at the server which probably made the clients and database ignore their own local files. Adding your line into the central file fixed it.